# How to set the a Visual Studio IDE to dark mode on Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, colors, background-color, uicolor

I just got my new MacBook and I downloaded Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac, but I can not enable the dark mode and the white one literally kills my eyes in Night.

The usual way to do this doesn't work for me, because there isn't dark mode in the Preferences. (Preferences/Environment/Visual Style/User Interface theme)

Answer (score 5):

`Menu` ➡️ `Visual Studio` ➡️ `Preferences`

[image: menu screenshot]

[image: change visual style theme screenshot]

[image: change text editor style screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I use Visual Studio Code. If you go to the Code menu item and click on preferences. When the preferences open the menu's show the items in the figure below.[image]

At the bottom of the preferences menu panal is a option for 'Color Theme'. Click on Color Theme and select a dark theme from the collection of themes shown..

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2019 - Click Tools > Options

Go to Environment > General tab and select the colour theme from the dropdown

-- I've just noticed that you're using a Mac.  The below was on Windows 10.  I'm not sure if this will be different on a Mac. --

[image]

Comment: Hi Paul - [it's different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63252931/185123)